# ¿Cómo hacer un contador binario?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Quiero que cuando le haga click a un botón HTML, en la consola me marque el número "0", y al hacerle otro click me marque el número "1", y así se intercalen en "0" "1", "0" "1" hasta el infinito.

Lo que he conseguido es esto (que está mal porque no retroce al cero, sino que se pasa al "2", "3", "4", etc):

```
$( 'bottom' ).click( function (  ) {
  var n = 0;
  console.log( n++ )
} )
```

Comment: Edu, bienvenido a SOes. Te recomiendo hacer el [tour] para comprender mejor el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: Creo que deberías reformular la pregunta porque leyendo los comentarios, lo que necesitás es otra cosa que no tiene nada que ver con el contador binario.

Answer (score 3):

Podría ser que el origen de la pregunta esté en llamarle "contador" cuando lo que se requiere es lo que en inglés se conoce como "toggle button" que en español se podría traducir como botón de activación.

A continuación un ejemplo.

Al hacer clic en el botón se cambia el color del div de aguamarina a gris oscuro y viceversa. Para esto se utiliza el [operador condicional (ternario)](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Operadores/Conditional_Operator) cuya sintaxis es

```
condición ? expr1 : expr2
```

```js
document.getElementById('boton').addEventListener('click', activar);

function activar() {
  var elDiv = document.getElementById('elDiv');
  
  // Se utiliza un operador ternario para asignar un valor o el otro
  (elDiv.className=='cero')?elDiv.className='uno':elDiv.className='cero';
 
}
```

```css
.cero, .uno {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

.cero {
  background-color: darkgrey;
}

.uno {
  background-color: aquamarine;
}
```

```html
<input id="boton" type="button" value="Cambiar color">
<div id="elDiv" class="cero"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

No entiendo porqué tiene que ser un "contador".

Si lo que quieres es mostrar `0` o `1`, puedes hacerlo de esta manera:

```js
function mostrar_valor() {
  // Obtener el valor del campo de texto:
  var vlr = document.getElementById('txt_valor').value;

  // Evaluar el valor obtenido y asignar un nuevo valor:
  switch (vlr) {
    case "0":
      vlr = "1";
      break;
    case "1":
      vlr = "0";
      break;
  }
  // Establecer el valor al campo de texto:
  document.getElementById('txt_valor').value = vlr;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="txt_valor" readonly value="0" />
<input type="button" id="btn_mostrar_valor" value="Mostrar valor" onclick="mostrar_valor()" />
```

Comment: Exactamente quiero hacer un botón, que cuando le de click estilice a otro elemento, digamos que le cambie el color de fondo a un div a azul, pero que cuando le vuelva a dar click se lo regrese a como estaba, y asi cuando le vuelva a dar click lo vuelva a poner azul. Para eso supongo que necesito un contador, para que mediante la condicional if, le indique que si doy click y vale "0" me de un estilo, y si le doy click y vale "1" me de otro.

Comment: @edu, la respuesta que he dado le puede funcionar para lograr lo que usted dice en su comentario. Inténtelo.

Answer (score 1):

prueba de esta forma:

```
    var n = 0;
    $( 'bottom' ).click( function (  ) {
console.log(n);
    if(n==0)
      n=1;
    else
      n=0;

    } )
```

Ejemplo de la logica:
https://jsfiddle.net/21j3gqfm/13/

Saludos.

Comment: No funciona amigo :(

Comment: te dejo este como ejemplo, espero te sirva.  https://jsfiddle.net/21j3gqfm/6/

Answer (score 1):

Usaré como base una de las respuestas. No es necesario condicionales complejos, podes usar el operador [%](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Operadores/Aritm%C3%A9ticos) para iterar y obtener un código más simple y fácil de mantener.

```js
function mostrarValor() {
  // Obtener el valor del campo de texto:
  var vlr = document.getElementById('txt_valor').value || 0;
  // Establecer el valor al campo de texto:
  document.getElementById('txt_valor').value = ++vlr % 2;
  document.getElementById('txt_valor').className = "_" + document.getElementById('txt_valor').value;
}
```

```css
._0 {
  background-color: red;
}
._1 {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="_0" id="txt_valor" readonly value="0" />
<input type="button" id="btn_mostrar_valor" value="Mostrar valor" onclick="mostrarValor()" />
```

Answer (score 0):

dos cosas respecto esta pregunta:

**primera:** a tu codigo original solo le falta %2 dentro del parentesis,y sacar la inicializacion de n fuera de la funcion:

> var n = 0; $( 'bottom' ).click( function (  ) {   console.log( n++
>   %2); } )

con esto, estarias mostrando en pantalla el resto de division del numero que hay activo (se va incrementando) entre 2 (lo cual sera siempre un alterno entre 0,1).

**segunda:** tu $('') hace referencia a bottom. creo que deberias hacerlo sobre el id del elemento #bottom o sobre una clase .bottom.

Comment: No funciona.... Mejor Te explico brevemente que es lo que quiero hacer, para ver si lo puedes hacer a tu manera: Un botón, que al darle click cambie el color de un div a azul, y cuando le vuelva a hacer click que retorne al color del div inicial (digamos blanco). Con un click que se le aplique un estilo, y con otro que retorne al que tenia antes.

Comment: a raiz de tu comentario, veo mas correcta la solucion que te indica Ruben, utilizando lo que se llama "toggle button". He corregido mi script, habia que sacar el *var n=0;* fuera de la función para inicializarlo.